# ASP.NET RAZOR - Projeto WEBSITE em execução no IIS (Homologação ou Produção) não consta a TAG HEAD

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Estou com um problema em meu projeto WEB , que ao ser executado por um IIS de um servidor, a `tag` html `HEAD` não aparece fechada e quando executado localmente a mesma aparece corretamente. Detalhe, ao inspecionar elemento no browser a mesma aparece, porem ao pressionar `ctrl+U`  não encontramos a mesma.
Já foi verificado as configurações de minificação e até mesmo compactação, porem nao consigo identificar o mesmo.

[image: Fonte no IIS Express]

[image: Fonte no IIS de um servidor remoto]

Answer (score 0):

Deve ser algum problema na configuração do seu IIS, você consegue rodar ou publicar no IIS o exemplo padrão de um novo projeto?
Tente colar a configuração do seu IIS no painel de controle ativar e desativar recursos do windows para compararmos se tem as mesmas configurações.